# How to grouping and reducing in Java8

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

As I have `List` of Subject

```
"Subjects":[
{"subject":"Math","grades":1},
{"subject":"Math","grades":2},
{"subject":"Math","grades":3},
{"subject":"Math","grades":3},
{"subject":"Lab","grades":10},
{"subject":"Lab","grades":12}
]
```

I want to grouping and reducing result like this

```
//Expected Result
"Subjects":[
{"subject":"Math","grades":[1,2,3]},
{"subject":"Lab","grades":[10,12]}
]
```

I'm curious about How can I Map and reduce Object In java8 Style.
I put obsolete code below.

My Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
List<Subject> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Subject("Math",1));
list.add(new Subject("Math",2));
list.add(new Subject("Math",3));
list.add(new Subject("Math",3));
list.add(new Subject("Lab",10));
list.add(new Subject("Lab",12));        
Map<String, Set<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
list.stream().forEach(subjects-> {
    if(result.get(subjects.getSubject())==null){
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(subjects.getGrades());
        result.put(subjects.getSubject(),set );
    }else{
        Set<Integer> set =result.get(subjects.getSubject());
        set.add(subjects.getGrades());
        result.put(subjects.getSubject(), set);
    }
    });

    result.forEach((key,val)->{
        System.out.println("KEY:"+key + " RESULT :"+val);
    });

}  


public class Subject {
private String subject;
private Integer grades;

public Subject(String subject , Integer grade) {
this.subject = subject;
this.grades = grade;
}

/** get set **/
}
```

Comment: Note: The `result.put(subjects.getSubject(), set);` line in the latter case is redundant.

Comment: even subject is getting duplicated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::getSubject)` and a `Collectors.mapping(Subject::getGrades, Collectors.toSet())` as a downstream.

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::getSubject,
                 Collectors.mapping(Subject::getGrades, 
                     Collectors.toSet())));
```

It would give you a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`.

```
{Lab=[10, 12], Math=[1, 2, 3]}
```